# Windows 10 BLE C#: Subscribing to notifications from the peripheral using cccd fails first time for non-bonded devices

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to develop a WPF app on windows 10 to communicate to a BLE device. I am using advertisement watcher class to scan for new devices.
I am expected to authenticate (proprietary) to the device before reading the data. Reading the data happens by subscribing to the client characteristic configuration descriptor of a particular characteristic.

The first time I find a device (which is of course Un bonded / Un paired) authentication works
The 2 way authentication happens by exchanging data over cccd of a particular characteristic which always works.

```
GattCommunicationStatus status = await **authenticationCharacteristic**.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(
                        GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
if(status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
{
//always success
}
```

The second step is to perform bonding using

```
DevicePairingResult result = await customPairing.PairAsync(ceremoniesSelected, protectionLevel);
```

Which succeeds.
After bonding is successful, the next step is to subscribe to cccd to receive data.

```
GattCommunicationStatus status = await **dataCharacteristic**.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(
                        GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
if(status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
{
}
```

This always throws an exception

**Exception:Thrown: "The attribute cannot be written. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80650003)" **

But in the subsequent connections when the devices are already bonded I am able to write to the client characteristic configuration descriptor and be notified about the data.

The issue is only when a new device is found and it is non bonded, writing to the data cccd always fails.

Is there a known issue?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Maybe the HRESULT originates from a GATT error sent by the remote device. Do you have any logs or sniffer data to see if that's the case?

Comment: Is it possible the peripheral is configured to only allow writing to the CCCD after bonding? Check your firmware's security settings.

Comment: I checked the sniffer logs. After bonding, the next step is to write to cccd of data characteristic. Windows actually never sends that packet. Looks like it is busy doing something else. There are a lot of ATT Reads happening after bonding. (not from my code)

Comment: If a bond is created in the current connection, write to cccd after bonding fails. 
If a bond was already established in a previous connection, then write to cccd works. This is what is observed consistently.

Comment: Update - I found that the windows BLE does a few other things upon bonding. It does a lot of ATT Reads such as ATT Read (Model Number ) ATT Read (Manufacturer  Name)  and all this happens on a different connection interval. This seems to be happening automatically (not triggered from the my code) Is the stack too busy during this time that it does not serve the requests from the app? (like writing to cccd)?